# Setting with accessors in initialize results in nil properties

Tags: ruby

Why does the last line result in nil and not `15`?

```
class TextC
  attr_accessor :thing1  
  def initialize
    thing1 = 15
    puts "thing: #{thing1}"
    some_method
  end  
  def some_method
    puts "ho there, wanderer"
  end
end  
tc = TextC.new
# thing: 15
# ho there, wanderer
# => #<TextC:0x007fe5617f1b30>
tc.thing1
# => nil
```

We've established that Ruby treats thing1=value as a setting of a local variable, but why?

Why does the accessor method NOT get inferred as the thing I'm trying to do, but some_method does?  Is the attr_accessor result only computed post-initialize?

Comment: It's treating it as a local.

Comment: Who proposed this question to be closed? It's silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attr_accessor :thing1` defines an attribute that accesses the instance variable `@thing1`. Instance variables are always prefixed with an `@`.

Assigning `thing1 = 15` creates a local variable within the `initialize` method. It does not call the attribute writer, so the value of the instance variable `@thing1` is not set. Because `@thing1` has not been assigned, the attribute reader `tc.thing1` will return `nil`.

Assignment expressions such as `thing1 = 15` that do not have an explicit receiver (`tc.thing1 = 15`) and that aren't to instance or class variables (`@thing1 = 15`, or `@@thing1 = 15`) in Ruby will *always* define and/or assign a local variable. To call the attribute writer (and have it set the instance variable), you need to explicitly specify the receiver, e.g. `self.thing1 = 15`.

The reason for is because in Ruby you don't declare variables before assigning them. An expression like `thing1 = 15` would be ambiguous, so Ruby chooses to make it always refer to the local variable.

There is no problem calling methods that are not attribute writers (methods with a name not ending in `=`) without an explicit receiver because there is no ambiguity. The expression `some_method` in `initialize` will therefore call the method `some_method`

The attribute defined by `attr_accessor` is available for use immediately. The same behaviour would be encountered in any method, not just `initialize`.

Comment: I think I accepted this answer prematurely, without digging deeper.  I've updated my question. Please take a look an feel free to edit your answer and explain deeper if you can please.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to explain this Ruby policy about what choice wins the ambiguity contest :]

Answer (score 0):

Because `@thing1` is not initialized, and when it is called, it returns `nil` by default.

Comment: How should it be initialized? Your answer is not useful hence the downvote!

Comment: @vee It answers exactly why it returns `nil`. If you want to ask your own question, open a new question.

Comment: Not a very complete explanation, though, no?